# Confusion about whether some single syllable words are stressed or unstressed

Tags: rhythm

From what I learned through reading, all auxiliaries are unstressed. What about certain conjunctions? It sounds like "as" is unstressed, but are "since" and "when" stressed? In thinking about this, I am having some difficulty. Please help.

I think that often my ear is weak.

Comment: You can stress a lot of words, including auxiliaries, if you want to put emphasis on them. I'd say "since" and "when" are usually not stressed, but _when_ they are stressed, or when they _are_ stressed, it'll be for emphasis.

Comment: Stresses are about speech. Any 'rules' you've read about are an attempt to understand how spoken language sounds, but those 'rules' don't impose back onto how people *actually* speak. Since your questions are often about poetic meter, you'll need to accept that some readers will mentally pronounce and stress different syllables in their heads as they read – often re-stressing *after* comprehending the full sentence. Punctuation and line-breaks can force a rhythm (awkwardly), but grammar alone can't suggest a rhythm until the full sentence (and larger context) has been understood.

Comment: Exactly. Writers have to figure out ways to represent the **sound** of English speech, since English orthography does a piss-poor job of it. And since English is stress-timed, phrases hafta fit into the stress and intonation.